# Clientes não se comunicam no mesmo jogo multiplayer em Java

Tags: java, swing, thread, socket, multithreading

Estou tentando fazer um jogo multiplayer simples de tanque implementando chat.
O jogo e o chat estão tudo ok! Porém, eu não consigo fazer com que 2 clientes visualizem o mesmo objeto `Arena`.

No caso, cada cliente que ingressar cria um tanque na arena. Porém, sempre que tento executar, ele cria uma arena diferente para cada jogador.

```
public class Arena extends JComponent implements MouseListener, ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private Tanque apontado;
    private int largura, altura;
    private HashSet<Tanque> tanques;
    private Tiro tiro;
    private Timer contador;
    private long agora;

    public Arena(int largura, int altura) {
        this.largura = largura;
        this.altura = altura;
        tanques = new HashSet<Tanque>();
        tiro = new Tiro(-40, -10, 0, null, -1);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        contador = new Timer(40, this);
        contador.start();
        agora = 1;
    }

    public void adicionaTanque(Tanque t) {
        tanques.add(t);
    }

    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(largura, altura);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(245, 245, 255));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, largura, altura);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(220, 220, 220));
        for (int _largura = 0; _largura <= largura; _largura += 20)
            g2d.drawLine(_largura, 0, _largura, altura);
        for (int _altura = 0; _altura <= altura; _altura += 20)
            g2d.drawLine(0, _altura, largura, _altura);
        // Desenhamos todos os tanques
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            t.draw(g2d);
        }
        tiro.draw(g2d);

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Tanque t : tanques)
            t.setEstaAtivo(false);
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            boolean clicado = t.getRectEnvolvente().contains(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (clicado) {
                t.setEstaAtivo(true);
                apontado = t;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            t.mover();
            t.calculaTempo();
        }
        colisao();
        tiro.mover();
        repaint();
    }

    public void colisao() {
        if (tiro.estaAtivo) {
            for (Tanque t : tanques) {
                if (t.getId() != tiro.getId()) {
                    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tiro.x - t.x, 2) + Math.pow(tiro.y - t.y, 2));
                    if (dist <= 20) {/* Distancia de acerto */
                        tiro.x = -10;
                        tiro.y = -10;
                        tanques.remove(t);
                        tiro.estaAtivo = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    /* Tanque detecta o míssil e tenta se esquivar */
                    if (dist < 100) {
                        t.setTempo(System.currentTimeMillis());

                        if (agora % 2 == 0)
                            t.girarAntiHorario(7);
                        else
                            t.girarHorario(7);

                        t.velocidade = 6;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            autoColisao(t);
        }

    }

    public void autoColisao(Tanque tanque) {
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {/* verifica a distancia para checar colisão entre os tanques */
            if (tanque.getId() != t.getId()) {
                double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tanque.x - t.x, 2) + Math.pow(tanque.y - t.y, 2));
                if (dist <= 30) { /* Colisão entre tanques */
                    if (t.velocidade > 0) {
                        t.velocidade *= -1;
                        t.girarAntiHorario(7);
                    } else {
                        t.velocidade = 2;
                        t.girarHorario(7);
                    }
                }

                if (dist < 80 && tanque.estaAtivo) {/* tanque inimigo tenta fugir */
                    t.setTempo(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    if (agora % 2 == 0)
                        t.girarAntiHorario(5);
                    else
                        t.girarHorario(5);

                    t.velocidade = 6;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            t.setEstaAtivo(false);
            if (t == apontado) {
                t.setEstaAtivo(true);
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    t.girarAntiHorario(3);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    t.aumentarVelocidade();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    t.diminuirVelocidade();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    t.girarHorario(3);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: {
                    atirar(t.getId());
                    agora = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void atirar(int id) {
        for (Tanque t : tanques) {
            if (t.estaAtivo) {
                if (!tiro.estaAtivo) {
                    tiro.x = t.x;
                    tiro.y = t.y;
                    tiro.angulo = t.angulo;
                    tiro.cor = Color.RED;
                    tiro.setId(t.getId());
                    tiro.estaAtivo = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Código Servidor:

```
public class Servidor extends Thread {


/* Aqui vou criar um Array list para armazenar o BufferedWiter de cada 
 * jogador que se conecta no site.
 * O restante das variaveis tem nomes sugestivos
 */
private static ArrayList<BufferedWriter> clientes;
private static ServerSocket servidor; 
private String nickname; /*essa variavel vai servir para armeznar o nome do jogador cliente que o servidor recebe*/
private Socket conexao;
private InputStream entrada;  
private InputStreamReader leitura_entrada;  
private BufferedReader buffer; 

Arena arena = new Arena(640, 480);
JFrame janela = new JFrame("JTank");




public Servidor(Socket conexao) {

    this.conexao= conexao;
    try {



        entrada  = conexao.getInputStream();
         leitura_entrada = new InputStreamReader(entrada);
         buffer = new BufferedReader(leitura_entrada);
  } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }                          
}


public void run(){


 janela.getContentPane().add(arena);
    janela.setResizable(false);
    janela.pack();
    janela.setVisible(true);        
    arena.adicionaTanque(new Tanque(500, 50, 180, Color.BLUE, 1));


  try{
    String mensagem;
    OutputStream ou =  this.conexao.getOutputStream();
    Writer ouw = new OutputStreamWriter(ou);
    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(ouw); 
    clientes.add(bfw);
    nickname = mensagem = buffer.readLine();


    while(!"Sair".equalsIgnoreCase(mensagem) && mensagem != null)
      { 



       mensagem = buffer.readLine();
       sendToAll(bfw, mensagem);
       System.out.println(mensagem);  


       }

   }catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

   }                       
}      

public void sendToAll(BufferedWriter bwSaida, String msg) throws  IOException 
{
BufferedWriter bwS;



for(BufferedWriter bw : clientes){
bwS = (BufferedWriter)bw;
if(!(bwSaida == bwS)){ 

 bw.write(nickname + " -> " + msg+"\r\n");
 bw.flush();          
}
}          
}


public void chama_arena() {

}


public static void main(String []args) {

try{    

JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("Porta do Servidor:");
JTextField txtPorta = new JTextField("12345");
Object[] texts = {lblMessage, txtPorta };  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, texts);
servidor = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(txtPorta.getText()));
clientes = new ArrayList<BufferedWriter>();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Servidor ativo na porta: "+         
txtPorta.getText());

 while(true){
 System.out.println("Aguardando conexão...");
 Socket conexao = servidor.accept();
 System.out.println("Cliente conectado...");
 Thread t = new Servidor(conexao);
  t.start();   
   }

}catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}                       


}   



}
```

Código cliente:

```
public class Cliente extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea texto;
    private JTextField txtMsg;
    private JButton btnEnviar;
    private JButton btnSair;
    private JLabel lblHistorico;
    private JLabel lblMsg;
    private JPanel pnlContent;
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream ou;
    private Writer ouw;
    private BufferedWriter bfw;
    private JTextField txtIP;
    private JTextField txtPorta;
    private JTextField txtNome;

    public Cliente() throws IOException {
        JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("Verificar!");
        txtIP = new JTextField("127.0.0.1");
        txtPorta = new JTextField("12345");
        txtNome = new JTextField("Cliente");
        Object[] texts = { lblMessage, txtIP, txtPorta, txtNome };
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, texts);
        pnlContent = new JPanel();
        texto = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        texto.setEditable(false);
        texto.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        txtMsg = new JTextField(20);
        lblHistorico = new JLabel("Histórico");
        lblMsg = new JLabel("Mensagem");
        btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.setToolTipText("Enviar Mensagem");
        btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
        btnSair.setToolTipText("Sair do Chat");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(this);
        btnSair.addActionListener(this);
        btnEnviar.addKeyListener(this);
        txtMsg.addKeyListener(this);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(texto);
        texto.setLineWrap(true);
        pnlContent.add(lblHistorico);
        pnlContent.add(scroll);
        pnlContent.add(lblMsg);
        pnlContent.add(txtMsg);
        pnlContent.add(btnSair);
        pnlContent.add(btnEnviar);
        pnlContent.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        texto.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
        txtMsg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
        setTitle(txtNome.getText());
        setContentPane(pnlContent);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(250, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /* Vou criar aqui um método chamado conectar.. Se conecta ao servidor */

    public void conectar() throws IOException {

        socket = new Socket(txtIP.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtPorta.getText()));
        ou = socket.getOutputStream();
        ouw = new OutputStreamWriter(ou);
        bfw = new BufferedWriter(ouw);
        bfw.write(txtNome.getText() + "\r\n");
        bfw.flush();




    }

    /*
     *  metodo Enviar mensagem é responsável pela troca de mensagens dentro do servidor
     */
    public void enviarMensagem(String msg) throws IOException {

        if (msg.equals("Sair")) {
            bfw.write("Desconectado \r\n");
            texto.append("Desconectado \r\n");
        } else {
            bfw.write(msg + "\r\n");
            texto.append(txtNome.getText() + " diz -> " + txtMsg.getText() + "\r\n");
        }
        bfw.flush();
        txtMsg.setText("");




    }

    /*
     * Método para ler as mensagens recebidas pelo servidor
     */
    public void escutar() throws IOException {



        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(inr);
        String msg = "";


        while (!"Sair".equalsIgnoreCase(msg))

            if (bfr.ready()) {
                msg = bfr.readLine();
                if (msg.equals("Sair"))
                    texto.append("Servidor caiu! \r\n");
                else
                    texto.append(msg + "\r\n");
            }
    }

    /*
     * Método usado quando o usuário clica em sair
     */
    public void sair() throws IOException {

        enviarMensagem("Sair");
        bfw.close();
        ouw.close();
        ou.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals(btnEnviar.getActionCommand()))
                enviarMensagem(txtMsg.getText());
            else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(btnSair.getActionCommand()))
                sair();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            try {
                enviarMensagem(txtMsg.getText());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Cliente app = new Cliente();

        app.conectar();
        app.escutar();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, acesse o link que segue para aprender a fornecer um **[mcve]** para que possamos executar o código e simular o problema.

Comment: Caroline, porque você acha que há duas arenas? Mais especificamente, em que ponto do debug você parou e inspecionou e viu que havia duas instâncias de Arena?

Comment: Quando cada cliente se conecta, ele deve crisr um tanque dentro da Arena. Mas, ele exibe uma Arena com apenas um tanque. Não mostra o tanque do adversário

Comment: Oi Caroline. Isso eu entendi, mas é preciso que você diga como você sabe isso, o que aparece no debug, etc.

Comment: P.s.: Quando responder a um comentário coloque para quem é com @CarolineTeixeira, por exemplo. Você recebe todas as notificações de comentários, mas os outros não. Por isso só vi seu novo comentário hoje.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que seu objeto Arena não é static, assim ele é um atributo da classe Servidor. Isso significa que cada vez que um objeto Servidor for criado um novo objeto Arena também será criado.

E isso acontece porque no código de tratamento de recebimento de conexões, em cada accept você cria um novo objeto Servidor, provavelmente porque no seu projeto você fez o Servidor herdar de Thread e imaginou que deveria criar uma nova instância para cada novo cliente (o que é parcialmente verdade).

Dito isso, se você tornar a Arena static vai resolver (parcialmente) o seu problema, mas o ideal seria revisar o projeto de forma que você separasse o tratamento dos clientes conectados do objeto que controla a arena por exemplo. No lado do servidor poderia repensar as tarefas que são executadas para ser mais modularizado.

Seria bom, como eu disse, separar pelo menos o tratamento de rede do tratamento de Arena.